# Configure Outlook Mail Settings Programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, email, pop3, profiles

Was wondering if there was a simple way to add and configure a POP3 server to Outlook's mail server settings programmatically?

Searching Google seems to yield results that tell me I have to reverse-engineer the gobbledygook stored under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles. My employer wanted to see if it was possible to quickly bang out a program to configure our users' POP3 settings (we're spread out around the country) and so far this is looking anything but simple.

I have VS2008 and all the Windows/Office built-in scripting tools at my disposal, though I don't know a lick of C++ (only C, C# and some web/linux stuff, I am self-taught).

Does anyone know of a simpler way to access Outlook's mail profiles in order to add to or tweak them?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook supports the PRF file as a means to add/configure mail accounts:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062(office.12).aspx

You could distribute the file itself to your users, or write a utility to create it and open it with Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to create an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) script to perform the changes through the front end.  That way you don't need to reverse engineer anything.  It's usually the quickest and easiest approach to making a change.  After the script is good to go, compile it and distribute it.  Have the end users run the application and they're done.