# Send Email From Specific Outlook Account Via Python?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I had some code that was written to email lab users whenever certain processes had finished running. This was sent from a gmail account, using SMTP.

However, my supervisor wants the mail to be sent from an official department address, which means that I have use Outlook and MAPI. I've had an account created which I want the email to originate from regardless of the lab machine the job is being run on. The problem is that I can only get email to send from the local Outlook account, and not all of the lab machines have a local account.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'user@domain.com'
mail.Subject = 'Message Subject'
mail.body = 'Message text. Message text'
mail.send
```

Surely there's a way to specify the username/password/server that I want the email to be sent from?

Answer (score 3):

I know this comes very late but this is how I've managed to select a specific e-mail address to send the e-mail from. The address needs to be among your outlook addresses.

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application') 

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Subject = "Test subject"
mail.To = "yourrecipient@gmail.com"

# If you want to set which address the e-mail is sent from. 
# The e-mail needs to be part of your outlook account.
From = None
for myEmailAddress in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if "iongroup.com" in str(myEmailAddress):
        From = myEmailAddress
        break

if From != None:
    # This line basically calls the "mail.SendUsingAccount = xyz@email.com" outlook VBA command
    mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From))

mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for configuring profiles. However, if you have an account configured in Outlook you may find the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class helpful. It allows to set an [Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869974.aspx) object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

You may find the following links helpful:

- [Configure Outlook Mail Settings Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556816/configure-outlook-mail-settings-programmatically)
- [White paper: Configuring Outlook profiles by using a PRF file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179052.aspx)

Comment: Astfiev - Can help me with this related post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612698/python-mail-send-successful-but-outlook-email-not-delivered

Answer (score 2):

As Eugene suggested, you can either manually create a POP3/SMTP account and assign it to the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property prior to calling `Send`, or you can create a new POP3/SMTP account dynamically using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession.Accounts.AddPOP3Account](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) method.